# `lein repl` failed with AssertionError

Tags: clojure, leiningen

I was trying out on a project generated by `lein new`. But I couldn't get `lein repl` working and the output was not very helpful in terms of trouble-shooting. Here's the stack trace:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.AssertionError: Assert failed: transport-fn, compiling:(/private/var/folders/02/rhhhdqmd3sn969wx0v68v3440b2221/T/form-init8538067533760352114.clj:1:125)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.load(Compiler.java:7526)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.loadFile(Compiler.java:7452)
    at clojure.main$load_script.invokeStatic(main.clj:278)
    at clojure.main$init_opt.invokeStatic(main.clj:280)
    at clojure.main$init_opt.invoke(main.clj:280)
    at clojure.main$initialize.invokeStatic(main.clj:311)
    at clojure.main$null_opt.invokeStatic(main.clj:345)
    at clojure.main$null_opt.invoke(main.clj:342)
    at clojure.main$main.invokeStatic(main.clj:424)
    at clojure.main$main.doInvoke(main.clj:387)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:137)
    at clojure.lang.Var.applyTo(Var.java:702)
    at clojure.main.main(main.java:37)
Caused by: java.lang.AssertionError: Assert failed: transport-fn
    at nrepl.core$connect.invokeStatic(core.clj:168)
    at nrepl.core$connect.doInvoke(core.clj:168)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:457)
    at nrepl.ack$send_ack.invokeStatic(ack.clj:45)
    at nrepl.ack$send_ack.invoke(ack.clj:41)
    at nrepl.server$start_server.invokeStatic(server.clj:146)
    at nrepl.server$start_server.doInvoke(server.clj:105)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:1096)
    at logical.core$eval1421.invokeStatic(form-init8538067533760352114.clj:1)
    at logical.core$eval1421.invoke(form-init8538067533760352114.clj:1)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.eval(Compiler.java:7062)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.eval(Compiler.java:7052)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.eval(Compiler.java:7052)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.load(Compiler.java:7514)
    ... 12 more
```

Here's the version of leiningen from `lein version`:
`Leiningen 2.8.2 on Java 11.0.1 OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM`

And here's the project.clj:

```
(defproject logical "0.1.0-SNAPSHOT"
  :description "FIXME: write description"
  :url "http://example.com/FIXME"
  :license {:name "EPL-2.0 OR GPL-2.0-or-later WITH Classpath-exception-2.0"
            :url "https://www.eclipse.org/legal/epl-2.0/"}
  :dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.9.0"]]
  :main logical.core
  :repl-options {:init-ns logical.core})
```

There's also nothing in ~/.lein but content generated by leiningen itself. This is run on a MacOS Mojave version 10.14.2.

Answer (score 1):

[This is a known issue with the latest 2.8.2 release of leiningen](https://github.com/technomancy/leiningen/issues/2506)

Easiest solution is probably to downgrade to 2.8.1 until the next release.

Comment: Thanks! How come that I didn't find the post.

Comment: That version of leiningen is only a few days old, so that's probably the reason you've not seen the report before